# Is there a stored procedure alike for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, stored-procedures

We have an existing functionality in our API that we're using a stored procedure that is save in MSSQL to query and export the data to form into a CSV file.

Can this be done in MongoDB? Is there such a stored procedure alike for MongoDB? I have research about 'Tasks' in MongoDB, can this be applied to query in the API? Or is there any other else?

Comment: There isn't a procedure built into SQL Serve that exports to a CSV. No doubt you *could* in MongoDB, but like SQL Server, you'd need to right your own procedure. Though, in truth, such tasks are often better written *outside* of the RDBMS and in a proper ETL or scripting tool.

Comment: @Larnu sorry for misunderstood. The export to csv is on the API side. Not on the SQL Server.

Comment: What specific functionality you are still looking for? For common data extraction and transformation, they should be achievable through aggregation framework.